# Could not find the module "@atlaskit/select"

Tags: node.js, npm

After npm install @atlaskit/select,Could not find module "@atlaskit/select"

node and npm are the latest version. Delete node_moudle folder.And re-install

```js
import { PopupSelect } from '@atlaskit/select';
```

Answer (score 1):

You normally don't need destructuring for that. Try

```js
import PopupSelect from '@atlaskit/select';
```

Comment: Words are powerless to express my gratitude.It has been bothering me for a long time.

Comment: I found that removing {} program could continue executing, but the referenced content could not be displayed.